# Libxls error : unable to open file this error was for R

Tags: r

While using R , my file is saved on desktop When I run

This code it gives me the above error
Setwd(“users/user name/desktop/“)

Comment: Please improve your post.

Comment: The correct function is `setwd` not `Setwd`.

Comment: R is case sensitive, so `Setwd` is different from `setwd`. When you get a `could not find function` error, that's the first thing you should check

Answer (score 0):

Isuggest that to check the work directory, and it is better to read any file on the same work space you choose 
from session -> set working directory ->choose directory

I hope my Answer help you.